# Infinite scroll on mobile with knockout and jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, cordova

I need to implement infinite scrolling for a search results page on mobile platforms.  We are using Knockout.js and PhoneGap with jQuery Mobile for a single-page-application.

The view in question has a div that is bound to the number of items returned.  I want to use knockout to bind to this div's scroll event so that infinite scrolling can be implemented.  The problem with this though is that jQuery mobile appears to be hijacking the scroll so that this event will now only trigger at the document level (the entire app must scroll instead of the divs requiring it).  A hacky solution I have is to add a callback to the window that calls the infinite scroll method from the search results view model.  I would like to avoid this if possible.

One solution another dev came up with is restructuring the site.  We currently have a universal footer (not the actual one):

```
<div class="navigation" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <!-- Div Contents -->
</div>
```

That is added to each page with jquery prepend.  Removing this and simply attaching it to the main index.html page did not appear to fix the issue but I have not gone much deeper with the fix.

I would like to stop jQuery/PhoneGap from hijacking the scroll and applying it to the entire page without changing the library files.  Is there any good solution to this or is the hack attempt the best option?  If we do go with that solution, how can we remove the event listener when a user navigates to a different "view"?

Comment: [this] http://fusiongrokker.com/post/jqmobile-iscrollview-infinite-scrolling might help you. What you need is [iScroll4.2] (https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll) and [iScrollView ] (https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview)

Comment: It does not appear to work :(